# Null Pointer Exception LinearLayout

Tags: java, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I got some problems with `NullPointerExceptions` but I got no clue how to fix it

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.bputs.MainActivity.setupUI(MainActivity.kt:63)
        at com.example.bputs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:31)
```

I can find the problem is in the `MainActivity`, but let me know how to change it so here's the `MainActivity`

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var productViewModel: ProductViewModel
    private lateinit var bottomSheet : BottomSheetBehavior<*>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        setupUI()
    }

    private fun setupUI() {
        productViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProductViewModel::class.java)
        rv_main_product.apply {
            layoutManager = if (resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity, 2)
            } else {
                GridLayoutManager(this@MainActivity,4)
            }
            adapter = ProductsAdapter(mutableListOf(), this@MainActivity, productViewModel)
        }

        rv_selected_produk.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            adapter = SelectedProductAdapter(mutableListOf(), this@MainActivity, productViewModel)
        }

        bottomSheet = BottomSheetBehavior.from(detail_order)
        bottomSheet.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
        detailBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (bottomSheet.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED || bottomSheet.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                bottomSheet.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            } else {
                bottomSheet.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
            }
        }

        productViewModel.fetchDummy()
        productViewModel.listenToProducts().observe(this, Observer {
            rv_main_product.adapter?.let { p ->
                if (p is ProductsAdapter) {
                    p.updateList(it)
                }
            }
        })
```

And here's the XML page

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/warnaUtama">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_atas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinssemibold"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Beautyper"
            android:textSize="38dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/warnaKedua"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_main_product"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="560dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:padding="8dp"/>

    <include layout="@layout/cart"/>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_shape">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/checkoutBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Checkout"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detailBtn"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_expand_less_24"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Please help me out of this problem, I'm new at this so now I'm Stuck. What can I do with the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: The code posted does not seem to match the error. There's no `setOnClickListener()` call on a `LinearLayout`, and the line numbers in the exception don't add up either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your code because you have removed lines that I feel would help me understand a little more. What if from the log I can understand that the problem may be due to 2 things that I imagine:

- You may be placing the id of detailBtn wrong, because the log says that your LinearLayout contains a ClickListener event, but I don't see it in the code
- You are calling setOnClickListener when the fragment is in another state than OnCreate, I'm not sure if the bottomSheet changes this state, but it could be the problem too. Because of this the app may not find the view.

Comment: The suggestion for the answer should be given as part of the comment. This answer  is not actual answer to this question

Comment: @KunalVarpe I can't comment, and I think my answer could have some kind of solution for this type of problems, so because of that I decide to answer